# Nodes are missing in Neoclipse graph

Tags: java, neo4j, neoclipse

[image]I have created Neo4j nodes and relatioships in java ,their values are coming from DB.When i am trying to display it on Neoclipse only first two nodes and their relationship is shown.
Code:

```
 GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("D://ws-NEO//Fade");
        Transaction tx=graphDb.beginTx();       
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
        conn=ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        Statement stat=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from Fade where App_Int_Id < 19";  //Two records are there in result
        ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery(sql);        
        String n1 = "",n2="",rel="",type="";
        while(rs.next()){
            n1=rs.getString(2);   
            n2=rs.getString(7);     
            rel=rs.getString(3);    
            type=rs.getString(4);           
        Node first=graphDb.createNode();
        first.setProperty("name", n1);  

        Node second=graphDb.createNode();
        second.setProperty("name", n2);         
        RelationshipType KNOWS = DynamicRelationshipType.withName(rel);     

            first.createRelationshipTo(second, KNOWS);      
        }
         tx.success();}
         finally
            {    tx.finish();
             graphDb.shutdown();
             conn.close();         
            }

It outputs two records in console:
node1 -- My App
node2 -- GCAM
relationship -- Cash focus
Node1 ceated  
Node2 ceated
relationship created
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
node1 -- My Test app
node2 -- GCAM
relationship -- Test Interface 11
Node1 ceated  
Node2 ceated
relationship created
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

however only single record is displayed in Neoclipse ,others are missing   . Plz guide.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a screenshot of your neoclipse screen?

Comment: I have attached screenshot and output in Eclipse console as well.

Comment: I also had the same problem back then.. i think it was a bug.. I don't know about it now though..

Comment: Note that Neoclipse only follows relationships from the starting node and so on from nodes it finds. So it will only find nodes somehow (transitively) connected to the starting node.

Comment: Ok So how to fix the same, Is there any other way? Plz guide.

Comment: Maybe have a look at other options for visualization, like the new web interface (aka Neo4j Browser), or see other options here: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neoclipse seems to have a default traversal depth of 1, giving you the result that you saw. But the traversal depth is adjustable, and neoclipse will remember the last-used traversal depth the next time it starts up.

To increment the traversal depth, you can click on the green '+' button in the toolbar at the top of the graph pane, and to decrement it you click on the green '-' button.

You can also change the starting node (for traversal purposes) by clicking on it. And double-clicking on a node causes all its neighbor nodes to display.

There is a lot more functionality, but you need to read the help documentation and play around with the tool to discover all its capabilities.

Comment: Only disconnected nodes and relationships were not shown in Neoclipse.